# facebook access token randomly expires

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am logging in via Javascript and I am using the method below to check facebook cookie and extract signed_request out of it:

```
function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
        $access_token = null;
        $expires = null;

        $signed_request = (isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id])) ? $this->parse_signed_request($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], $app_secret) : NULL;

        if (!is_null($signed_request)) {
            $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=&client_secret=".$app_secret."&code=$signed_request[code]";

            $access_token_response = $this->getDataFromUrl($url);           
            parse_str($access_token_response);
            $signed_request["access_token"] = $access_token;

            if($expires == 0){ $signed_request["expires"] = 0; }else{ $signed_request["expires"] = time() + $expires; }
        }
        return $signed_request;
    }
```

getDataFromUrl() function:

```
function getDataFromUrl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

On first response I successfully get **access_token** and **expires** attributes but I lost them on next request, either page refresh or navigating to another page.

Is there a solution to this or an alternative way to implement it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend combining the php-sdk with the js-sdk to automatically log the user in as is shown in the github example here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php

Comment: @TommyBs I guess I should go that way. I thought that implementing my own methods would be better. Thank you